# Fixed Row using Flexbox Grid

Tags: css, flexbox, css-position

I am using flexboxgrid css library (www.flexboxgrid.com) and I want to achive my first row to be fixed and stays the full width of the container.

I am currently ending up in the first row being fixed but not full width. Here is what I did so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="row center-xs middle-xs fixedHeader">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
      <div class="box">
        <h3>Fixed Header</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <div class="row center-xs middle-xs normalContent">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 col-lg-7">
      <div class="box">
        <h3>normal content</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.Wrapper{
     max-width: 1520px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 80px 40px;
}
.fixedHeader {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
}

.normalContent{
  min-height: 900px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

I have also done a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qdkLbak2/) for this. Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Once you remove the element from the normal flow with fixed positioning, you need to define a width. Try adding `width: 100%` or whatever width you need.

Comment: position:sticky might be an alternative ? https://jsfiddle.net/qdkLbak2/1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a width attribute to your "fixedHeader" class. I use the calc css function to make it 100% minus the padding in your "Wrapper" class.

```
.Wrapper{
     max-width: 1520px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 80px 40px;
}
.fixedHeader {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
}

.normalContent{
  min-height: 900px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

See http://caniuse.com/#search=calc for calc() compatibility

Answer (score 0):

You are using `position:fixed` that's why you are not getting the 100% width.

Add the width as well to your `.fixedHeader`

```
.fixedHeader {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: width set to 100% will make the fixed header go outside my wrapper

Comment: you can set it according to your wrapper size. it's just for example.